# How can i store data from two page in same id in PHP

Tags: html, mysql

I have two pages sample4.php and sample5.php where different data is been passed. I need to store both page value in same id currently it stores in different id.

sample4.php

```
  <form action = "sample5.php" method = "GET">    

     firstname: <input type = "text" name = "firstname" value="<?php echo @$firstname; ?>" />
     lastname: <input type = "text" name = "lastname" value="<?php echo @$lastname; ?>" />
       nationality: <input type = "text" name = "nationality" value="<?php echo @$nationality; ?>" />
     <input type = "submit" value="next" />
  </form>
```

Here i am passing firstname,lastname and nationality to next page sample5.php where extra two fields is added i need to store all value in same id but it actually stores first page value in one id and second page value in other id.Please help me to store both in same. Thanks in Advance

**sample5.php**

```
  <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                    $db = mysql_select_db("registration",$conn);

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO sampletable (firstname,lastname,nationality,mobileno,gender) VALUES ('". @$_GET['firstname']."','". @$_GET['lastname']. "' ,'". @$_GET['nationality']. "','". @$_POST['mobileno']. "','". @$_POST['gender']. "')";
                    $rep = mysql_query($sql);

 ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
         <form  action="sample5.php" method="POST">

        <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) { ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="act" value="edit"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

                <?php } else{ ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="act" value="add"/>
                <?php } ?>


         <label> Mobile No        </label>

    <input type="text" name="mobileno" value="<?php echo @$mobileno; ?>"><br>

         <label> Gender</label>

    <input type="text" name="gender" value="<?php echo @$gender; ?>"><br>

    <input type = "submit"  />        

    </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: use same name both in sample4.php and sample5.php

Comment: Sir, Can you pls specify which name should be same....?